# Compare & remove items from Listbox in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have two Listbox in asp.net webform application.

LIstBox1 has List of all Projects & ListBox2 has assigned project.

One page Load both ListBox1 is populated with all Project & ListBox2 is populated with assigned Project & I have a button which removed the Assigned Project from LIstbox2

```
var itms1 = ListBox1.Items;
            var itms2 = ListBox2.Items;
            foreach (var itm in itms2)
            {
                if (itms1.Contains(itm)) itms1.Items.Remove(itm); 

            }
```

I get error error on this as shown in image:

[image]

I simply want to compare ListBox2 with ListBox1 and remove matching ListBox2 values from ListBox1.

I tried different varies but I keep getting similar error or it won't work.

ListBox show ProjectName as Text and ProjectID as Listbox Values

I am using asp.net webform application on .net framework 4.5

Comment: Why did you put the items in the listbox in the first place if you want to remove them? Simply do not put them in the listbox.

Comment: This is actually an EDIT so user can change there selection and for this reason i have to show what user had selected previous in listbox2 but i want to remove same project from Listbox1 which are already present in ListBox2.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```
itms1.RemoveAll( item => itms2.Contains(item));
```

This code removes all items that are in list2

Comment: It doesnt show me RemoveAll option rather it show me only Remove & RemoveAt option

Comment: The reason RemoveAll isnt showing is because you are working with a ListBox.ObjectCollection.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
 foreach (ListItem itemA in LisyBox2.Items)
        {
               for (int i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                {
                    if (ListBox1.Items[i].Text == itemA.Text)
                    {
                        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```